# Cannot connect to MSSQL server using node-mssql

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, database

```js
const sql = require("mssql");

var sqlconfig = {
   
    server:"192.168.200.5",
    database:"DATA",
    user: "labo",
    password: "*********",
    connectionTimeout: 30000,
    port: 1433,
    dialect: "mssql",
     dialectOptions: {
           "instanceName": "SQLEXPRESS"
     },
 };
 
new sql.ConnectionPool(sqlconfig).connect().then(pool => {
        console.log(pool);                        return pool.query('select * from data where id = 2')
    }).then(result=> {
         console.dir(result)
    }).catch(err => {
       console.log(err);
    })
```

Problem: Return Login failed for user 'Labo' ELOGIN when trying to login to Microsoft SQL Server using node.js.

What I have tried: Grab the example codes on npm to find the avoid extra problems. Error still persisted.

What I suspect: The username I inserted was "labo" but the one returned from err was 'Labo' (with capitalized 'L'). Is this a bug?

This is my code

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log. It will contain the specific reason for the login failed. Make sure the instance is configured to allow SQL Authentication.

Comment: Do you have TWO instances of SQL Server?

Comment: @DanGuzman A C#-based application connected well. It's unfortunate that I can't directly access the server.

Comment: @sepupic I don't think so. But the SQL version might be outdated. It was built 10 years ago approximately.

Comment: Why are you specifying the port *and* the instance name? A named instance is unlikely to ever be running on port 1433.

Comment: @T.Dong, if you can't access the log, find someone who can. That will greatly help troubleshooting.

Comment: Your connection string will bring you to the default instance, that's why I asked you if you have 2 instances. Of course you could put your Express on 1433,but it's very unlikely. So may be you just connect to a wrong instance

Comment: @sepupic I reverted to mssql@3.3.0 and everything worked fine. Seems like a bug in the latest version.